# Intel Virtualization Technology not showing up on apparently supported chip

Tags: cpu, dell-vostro, hardware-virtualization

I have a laptop with an Intel i3-3217U CPU which according to the Intel's [website](http://ark.intel.com/products/65697/) supports Vtx, however when I run the Intel Processor Id Utility or Securable it reports that Virtualization Technology is not supported on the machine.

This is a Dell Vostro 2521 and in the BIOS there is an option for Virtualization and this is enabled, I am running Windows 8 Pro. 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked to ensure you're using the latest BIOS revision?

Comment: I wasn't the Dell website is misleading, but I just upgraded and its still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I disabled Virtualization in the BIOS, restarted and Windows wouldnt boot. Re-enabled Virtualization and now everything is working correctly.

I also turned off Hyper-V in Windows Features at the same time so not sure which thing actualy did the trick.

Comment: Turning off Hyper-V did the trick. Intel doesn't support nested virtualization, so once you're virtualizing, virtualization is no longer supported.

Comment: I have an ASUS P6T SE with the final BIOS, and Virtualization was enabled. Intel tool did not detect it. Then turning it off. Cold starting the computer again, it now shows correctly (Virtualization enabled) in the Intel tool. Thanks. Using that machine for Hyper-V.